# Error installing mongodb , broken ubuntu dependency

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Trying to install mongo with below command

```
rahul@rahul ~ $ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mongodb-org is already the newest version (3.6.2).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: try `apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: Tried but no help
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-tools_3.6.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (3.6.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_3.6.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.2.11-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_3.6.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Did you adding the MongoDB Repository ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue installing mongodb-org on an Ubuntu 18 box.

The issue was that a version of mongodb was already installed, and it had to be removed before I continued.

The solution was to run the following:

```
sudo apt remove mongodb-org
sudo apt purge mongodb-org
sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

More info can be found on the [Mongodb website](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/installation-ubuntu-community-troubleshooting/#unable-to-install-package-due-to-dpkg-deb-error) - apparently this is a frequent enough issue that they had to address it there!